# sprint boot - redis key delimiter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis

I have a redis resource class `Product` that is annotated with `@RedisHash("product")`. When I save a new product using a `CrudRepository<Product, Long>`

```
product.setId("0")
dao.save(product)
```

and then check the keys in the redis database, I see the key `product:0`

How can I change the delimiter `:` to `.` ? So that a new product is saved with the key `product.0`

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the delimiter, you have to override function createKey(String keyspace, String id) of RedisKeyValueAdapter class.

Original implementation in Spring Framework is the following:

```
public byte[] createKey(String keyspace, String id) {
    return toBytes(keyspace + ":" + id);
}
```

You have to override it and change the delimiter.